# Error Installing Latest Haskell source on Ubuntu Server 12.04

Tags: linux, haskell, ubuntu, installation

I trying to install the latest ghc (ghc-7.8.4-src.tar.bz2) on my ubuntu server version 12.04.

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 12.04 LTS
Release:        12.04
Codename:       precise
```

I know ghc needs a pre existing installation to compile. So I tried with `sudo apt-get install ghc` and `sudo apt-get install haskell-platform`. Either case gives me the below error when I run `sudo make install`. ***i)*** Any ideas on solving this? Also, ***ii)*** it takes quite a long time to compile, and even get to this point. So is there a way to vet the compilation before hand?

```
...
Installing library in /usr/local/lib/ghc-7.8.4/ghc-prim-0.3.1.0
ghc-cabal: Error: Could not find module: GHC.PrimopWrappers with any   suffix:
["p_hi"] in the search path: ["dist-install/build"]
make[1]: *** [install_packages] Error 1
make: *** [install] Error 2
```

Comment: Have you install all required dependencies:  sudo apt-get install  libgmp-dev zlib1g-dev libgl1-mesa-dev libglc-dev freeglut3-dev libedit-dev libglw1-mesa-dev libglw1-mesa

Comment: I've used this script https://raw.github.com/chrisprobst/ubuntu-raring-haskell/master/install.sh

Comment: I tried the a fresh install of ubuntu on vagrant (`http://files.vagrantup.com/precise32.box`), and the dependencies you listed, using your script. And I'm still getting the same error (http://pastebin.com/NksSjSkg).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, solved this with the help of the fine folks on IRC (#haskell). Turns out that compiling ghc from source is really reserved for hacking on the compiler itself. So I was recommended the GHC binary package. That's presently [GHC 7.8.4](https://www.haskell.org/ghc/download_ghc_7_8_4#x86linux).

From there, `./configure` and `sudo make install` worked for my platform. With a working ghc, you can then get the [latest Cabal](https://www.haskell.org/cabal/download.html). Cabal library needs to be built, and cabal-install is a binary. They are currently both at 1.22.0.0.

Hope this helps someone.